# I bought a model on fiverr in .obj but it was sent as .txt

Tags: objects, file-format

[image: this is what shows up when i open the file]

Does anybody know how to make this into an obj file? Am I just stupid?

Comment: Rename it to .obj

Comment: It is just a text file so @tkausl suggestion should work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: no stupid questions only stupid answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJ is basically a text file. It should be fine if you renamed the file and changed the extention from .txt to .obj.